# flex Datagrid itemRenderer overriding getCurrentState

Tags: apache-flex

I made a `GridItemRenderer` with an error state, which displays a red border line after validating `data[column.dataField]` content, everything but the scrolling works...
Lets say the top item is in an error state and everything else is fine because `data[column.dataField]` its only null in the top cell, then i scroll the bar down one row, when the new row is about to display, my overrided getCurrentRendererState gets called, and checks if its null, it should change to normal state but here is the thing, at this point, `data[column.dataField]` still has the top's row value, so after doing my validation, `data[column.dataField]` is still null, even when the current cell is displaying the current data...
So, how can i get the current cell value?

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import custom_events.DataGridValidationEvent;
        private function creationComplete():void{
            owner.parent.parent.addEventListener(DataGridValidationEvent.VALIDATE,doValidation);
        }
        private function doValidation(e:DataGridValidationEvent):void{
            currentState=data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error";
        }
        override public function get label():String{
            return lblCell.text;
        }
        override public function set label(value:String):void{
            currentState=data?data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error":"normal"
            lblCell.text=value;
        }
        override protected function getCurrentRendererState():String{
            return data?data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error":"normal";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="error"/>
</s:states>
<s:Rect left="1" right="0" top="1" bottom="0" includeIn="error">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xFF001A" weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
<s:Label id="lblCell" width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle"
         paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="3" maxDisplayedLines="1"
         showTruncationTip="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening to the Data change event, and doing the validation there did it, its all good now.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import custom_events.DataGridValidationEvent;
        private function creationComplete():void{
                owner.parent.parent.addEventListener(DataGridValidationEvent.VALIDATE,doValidation);
                addEventListener(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE,setState);
            }
            private function doValidation(e:DataGridValidationEvent):void{
                currentState=data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error";
            }
            private function setState(e:FlexEvent):void{
                currentState=data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error";
            }
            override public function get label():String{
                return lblCell.text;
            }
            override public function set label(value:String):void{
                currentState=data?data[column.dataField]?"normal":"error":"normal"
                lblCell.text=value;
            }
            override protected function getCurrentRendererState():String{
                return currentState;
            }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="error"/>
</s:states>
<s:Rect left="1" right="0" top="1" bottom="0" includeIn="error">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xFF001A" weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
<s:Label id="lblCell" width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle"
         paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="3" maxDisplayedLines="1"
         showTruncationTip="true"/>
```